# is there any issue in select query after executing delete query in presto cli?

Tags: hive, hdfs, presto

I have presto hive and hdfs setup, and i have a table customer which has data in it(data stored in hdfs location /presto/customer.avro).

hive table also has the schema and metadata info.
on executing select * query in presto cli it gives all 3 records which were inserted;

On executing delete from customer; in presto cli all data are deleted.

Again on persisting data its gets reflected in hdfs customer file but presto select * query show no records.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: does select * query works after executing delete from table_name query in presto_cli

Answer (score 1):

If you have created an external table, then delete command will just remove the table from metastore and would not delete the underlying files.
Check properties related to external tables here https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html